# Accessing a Azure Key Vault secret works on server box but not local?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-keyvault

We have a Key Vault in a resource group in an Azure instant.

We have a user in the US (ME) and a user in different country (FU).

Both of use have many things in common, namely:

Using same version of VS 2017.
Running the exact same code.
Our VS user account is the same (a user in our Azure AD instance).

We are using a Managed Identity

If I run the code in US (logged in in VS as the FU), I am able to read the secret and display on the screen.

If the FU(logged in in VS as the FU but in another country), when he runs the code it throws the following exception

Operation returned an invalid status code '**Unauthorized**'

The line of code that throws the error is:

```
var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("https://XXXXXXX.vault.azure.net/secrets/username")
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

We have both installed Azure CLI 2.0.

However, I found these stipulations at this [site](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet#use-key-vault-from-app-service-with-managed-service-identity).

Your on-premise active directory is synced with Azure AD.

You are running this code on a domain joined machine.

Neither of these are true in our case.

Possibly a good test of these would for our vendor to allow me to remote into his machine and put my identity on VS and then run the code.

If we still get the error, then it is very likely this is our problem.

The above link said we could "[Run the application using a service principal in local development environment](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet#running-the-application-using-a-service-principal-in-local-development-environment)"

Would that fix the problem???

I am fairly new to Azure and C#. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What the meaning of `If the FU(logged in in VS as the FU but in another country)`?

Comment: Did you set the `Firewalls and virtual networks` in the portal?

Comment: >What the meaning of If the FU(logged in in VS as the FU >but in another country)?                                                       This means that the foreign user is logged in to Visual Studio as himself, but is in a foreign country)